# Javascript automatic file download

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to automate csv file download on a webpage if there are some errors in the file upload. The problem i am facing is that the file that gets download has one blank column infront which is blank and after that it has data.

I want to remove this blank column. Can somebody help me with this.

```
var ErrorsInUpload=[[',carId','Version','model','price','defect\n']];
         <c:forEach var="message" items="${failureMsg}" >
             ErrorsInUpload.push('<c:out value="${message.carId}"/>',
                     '<c:out value="${message.version}"/>',
                     '<c:out value="${message.model}"/>',
                     '<c:out value="${message.price}"/>',
                     '<c:out value="${message.defect}"/>\n'
                     );
         </c:forEach>


        if(ErrorsInUpload.length>=2){
         var csvString = ErrorsInUpload;
         var a         = document.createElement('a');
         a.href        = 'data:attachment/csv,' +  encodeURIComponent(csvString);
         a.target      = '_blank';
         a.download    = 'uploadFailure.csv';

         document.body.appendChild(a);
         a.click();
        }
 });
```

Comment: is this coldfusion?

Comment: change `',carId',` to `'carId',`

Comment: Looks like JSP @DanielA.White

Comment: if i remove the comma before ,carId the header starts from the 1st column. But the body starts after one blank column. which i don't want.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting with a comma, which creates an empty column. Remove the comma in ',carId'.

Comment: if i remove the comma before ,carId the header starts from the 1st column. But the body starts after one blank column.